# Excluding code(components\routing) in non production environments using angular (TypeScript \ Webpack)?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I have an application with no login page. The login will be done using some kind of SSO.
In the meantime, I would like to add a login component & routing path for so our QA\Dev could work more efficiently.

I know that there's an `environment.ts` file with a production property and that I could if/else this out, but I **don't** want my source files to include the component & the routing on production deploys.

I know I can build external tools for doing this (chrome extension\desktop app etc.), but since we have too many environments, I'd prefer this to be a link on top of my application.

Is there any way (maybe via some kind of `@Attribute`) that I can exclude chunks of code for a specific environment? Is there any other best practice for doing something like this? I guess that if this is possible it will be some kind of Typescript & Webpack feature.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any Webpack loaders that can toggle code by environment using attributes, but if you really want one, you can easily make your own (and then share it on GitHub):

https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/how-to-write-a-loader

Just create a simple loader that retrieves the source code of your app as a string, and then cuts out classes that doesn't have attributes that match the current environment on `environment.ts` using regex/simple string replace.

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 - Thanks for your response. I thought about doing something similar. I'm still hoping for some better practice or some existing plugin\loader.

Answer (score 0):

No sure if that would be feasible in you case. But what I used to solve similar case is a second `main.ts` file. Let's assume that one is calls `main_withSSO.ts`(original one) and the second one `main_noSSO.ts`. The Second one will have extra login page/ routing component included.

Now your webpack configuration could depend on the env variable which would determine main.ts file used in the build process.

example webpack config:

```
function getMainEntryFile(env) {
    if (env && env.sso) {
        return "PATH-TO-main_withSSO.ts"
    }
    return "PATH-TO-main_noSSO.ts";
}

module.exports = function(env){
    return {
        "entry": {
            "main": [
                getMainEntryFile(env)
            ],
        }
    }
```

you can build it using following command

```
npm run clean && webpack --env.sso
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Doing something like that has a major overhead and that's not what I'm looking for.